# Property 'onSnapshot' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<unknown>'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to detach listener from cloud Firebase, but I still get this error.

> Property 'onSnapshot' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection'

Do you know, what sould I import? I directly copy this code from Firebase documentation.

```
let unsub = this.firestore.collection('cities').onSnapshot(() => {
});

// Stop listening for changes
unsub();
```

This is my constructor and import:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

constructor(public firestore: AngularFirestore) {}
```

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: what is `db` equal to?

Comment: oh, sorry, it should be "firestore" - in constructor (edited)

Answer (score 3):

`AngularFirestore` is a class in the library `angularfire`, according to the source code https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/firestore/firestore.ts#L106, the class `AngularFirestore` does not contain any method called `onSnapshot()`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });
```

In this case `db` is equal to `firebase.firestore();`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

If you want to use AngularFire then you can use `snpashotChanges()`:

```
this.shirtCollection = afs.collection<Shirt>('shirts');
    // .snapshotChanges() returns a DocumentChangeAction[], which contains
    // a lot of information about "what happened" with each change. If you want to
    // get the data and the id use the map operator.
    this.shirts = this.shirtCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Shirt;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
```

Comment: And can you please tell me, how to import or how to use this pure JS lib, please?

Comment: follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: I am trying to set it up by the documentation, but there are using only node.js or plain javascript, in combination with angular, this doesnt work...

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown' - when I hover over actions => actions.map(a => ...)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but u don't have to use `map` you can use `return this.shirtCollection.snapshotChanges()` in ur service class and subscribe to it in ur component