# refer doc id using where condition in snapshotChanges()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am fetching data using `snapshotChanges()`. I want to add `where` condition to it and fetch data of only **1 doc** from `collection`.

Below is my code:

```
this.firestore.collection('notifications' , ref => ref 
 .where(document id , "==" , "1")  // giving error
)
.snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(response => {
  if(!response.length){
    console.log("no data available");
    return false;
  }
  this.notifyarr = [];   
  for(let item of response){
    this.notifyarr.push(item.payload.doc.data());
    console.log(this.notifyarr);
    this.notification_length = this.notifyarr.length;
    console.log(this.notification_length);
  }
})
```

This line of code is giving error `.where(document , "==" , "1")  // giving error`

How do we refer a document using `.snapshotChanges()` ?

Comment: What error you are getting..!?

Comment: `document` is not the right word, i want to know how to refer a `doc`, what to write in place of `document` ??

Comment: You are referring the document in correct way, there is no problem with your reference. What error you are getting..?!

Comment: nope - error - Argument of type 'Document' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FieldPath'.
  Type 'Document' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: trying with ` .where(ref.id , "==" , "1") ` but it says `no data available

Comment: The error clearly says , you are giving an invalid value ,you should pass string type value

Comment: i think the correct way can be `ref.id` but it is not returning result

Comment: The first parameter of where clause should be a field in the document you want to query against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query to check a `documentid` is equal to the value then you should do the following:

```
where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==" , "1")
```

Comment: i tried `i used ` firebase.firestore().collection("notifications").doc(this.loggedInuser) .onSnapshot(doc=> {` , thanks for the answer. What is the difference between snapshotChanges and onSnapshot as i am getting new entries

Comment: `onSnapshot()` is used in firebase javascript sdk, while `snapshotChanges()` is used in angularfire library, if u are using angular just use angularfire library

Comment: Check my answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054405/angularfire-snapshotchanges-vs-firestore-javscript-library-onsnapshot https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154574/7015400 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358077/property-onsnapshot-does-not-exist-on-type-angularfirestorecollectionunknown

Comment: i am using both , but as i am using ionic, from future i'll stiick to `snapshotChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

If you know you only want a single document using its ID, why don't you just build a [AngularFirstoreDocument](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#using-angularfirestoredocument) to the desired document and call [snapshotChanges](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges) on that reference?

```
this.firestore.collection('notifications').doc(id).snapshotChanges()...
```

No need to bother building a query that only gives you a single document.

Comment: i used `    firebase.firestore().collection("notifications").doc(this.loggedInuser)
    .onSnapshot(doc=> {` , thanks for the answer. What is the difference between `snapshotChanges` and  `onSnapshot` as i am getting new entries

Comment: The documentation I linked to describes the behavior of the various methods to get data.  I suggest using that as a reference.